# Add elements to model

Tags: angular, typescript

I´m trying to add some elements in a model. I don´t know exactly how works in Angular so i try .add

Model

```
export class Profile {
  id: number;
  nombre: descripcion;
}
```

TS

```
 perfilesTodos: Profile[];
 response["body"].forEach((index: number) => {
        if (response["body"] == 1) {
          this.perfilesTodos.push(index, "Arson");
        } else if (response["body"] == 2) {
          this.perfilesTodos.push(index, "Administrador de entidad");
        } else if (response["body"] == 3) {
          this.perfilesTodos.push(index, "Administrador de grupo");
        } else if (response["body"] == 4) {
          this.perfilesTodos.push(index, "Gestor");
        } else if (response["body"] == 5) {
          this.perfilesTodos.push(index, "Instalador");
        }
      });
```

Return

> Can not assign an argument of type "number" to the parameter of type
>   "Profile"

Somebody know how add elements in an array using a model?

Comment: Please specify the response as well that you're getting. We don't know what's `response.body`

Comment: it should be ```this.perfilesTodos.push({id: index; nombre: "Arson" });```

Comment: Using this.perfilesTodos.push({id: index; nombre: "Arson" }); error fixed but console.log(this.perfilesTodos) return null. The response return  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: do it for all items for push for e.g: this.perfilesTodos.push({id: index; nombre: "Instalador"}); based on value of response["body"] your array will be filled, log the response["body"] and see what is it?

Comment: In this case return Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.  response["body"].forEach((index: number) => {
        console.log(index);
        this.perfilesTodos.push({ id: index, descripcion: "Arson" });
      });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly helps to understand that [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) takes varargs arguments. So below would (like you are doing in your code) would push many elements to a list:

```
list.push(1,2,3,4,5);
```

So what you need to do is to add a `Profile` to a list of profiles

```
this.perfilesTodos.push({ id: index, nombre : "Arson"});
```

Now to omit all those `if else` statements, one could create a simple string array

```
const data: string[] = ['Arson', 'Administrador de entidad', 'Administrador de grupo', 'Gestor', 'Instalador']
```

get rid of all if else and simply do

```
perfilesTodos: Profile[] = [];
response["body"].forEach((id: number) => {
    this.perfilesTodos.push({id, nombre: data[ response["body"] - 1 ]});
});
```

Of course you'll also have to change `nombre`'s type, since there is no such thing as `description`- it's string.

---

What still looks very strange is that you are first looping over `response['body'] as it were an array, and later try to make an equality check on a number...

Comment: response["body"].forEach((id: number) => {
        this.perfilesTodos.push({
          id,
          descripcion: "Arson"
        });
      }); apparently works, but i need to create if.. else to set names with different id´s.

Comment: No, as I explained you don't need to @ElHombreSinNombre

Comment: In this case   this.perfilesTodos.push({
          id,
          name: this.data[response["body"] - 1]
        }); return null name i fix it using  this.perfilesTodos.push({
          id,
          descripcion: this.data[id - 1]
        });

Answer (score 0):

you need to push an object base of Profile class **shape** or an instant of peofile class

```
 perfilesTodos: Profile[] = []; //  array default value

 response["body"].forEach((index: number) => {
        if (response["body"] == 1) {
          this.perfilesTodos.push({ id: index, nombre : "Arson");
        } else if (response["body"] == 2) {
          this.perfilesTodos.push({ id: index, nombre :"Administrador de entidad"});
        } else if (response["body"] == 3) {
          this.perfilesTodos.push({ id : index, nombre : "Administrador de grupo" });
        } else if (response["body"] == 4) {
          this.perfilesTodos.push({ id :index, nombre :"Gestor"});
        } else if (response["body"] == 5) {
          this.perfilesTodos.push({ id: index, nombre  :"Instalador"});
        }
      })
```

> when you mark the perfilesTodos as profile array this mean all array
>   item has to be base of that type shape so you need to push ethier an
>   instant of profile class or an object has that same proprties

Comment: Return 'undefinied' in console. Maybe if..else doesn´t work?

Comment: I try  simple code like this if (response["body"] == 1) {
          console.log("entra");
        } in foreach and doesn´t pass

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre the error is related to array push method

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre may be you need to init the perfilesTodos array with empty array check my answer